# How to extract timezone from localtime()?

Tags: perl, timezone, localtime

I'm using the following code to print the current time.

```
use Getopt::Long;
use Time::Local;
sub gettime
{
        my $t = time();
        my ($sec,$mn,$hr,$mday,$mon,$yr,@left, $dstr);

        ($sec,$mn,$hr,$mday,$mon,$yr,@left) = localtime($t);
        $yr  = $yr-100+2000;
        $mon += 1;
        $dstr = sprintf "%02d:%02d:%02d (%02d-%02d-%04d)", $hr, $mn, $sec, $mon, $mday, $yr;
        print $dstr;
}

gettime();
```

I can set the timezone using:

```
local $ENV{TZ} = ":/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles";
```

How can I extract the timezone from `localtime()`?

Comment: $yr = $yr-100+2000 is really (documented) year+1900, though I sure your form is optimized away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `strftime()`:

```
use POSIX;
$tz = strftime("%Z", localtime());
```

Or, calculate the difference between `localtime()` and `gmtime()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the timezone as well as the offset from UTC:

```
perl -MPOSIX -e 'print strftime "%Z (%z)\n",localtime'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is pure Perl approach to calculate current timezone without using external modules:

```
sub get_timezone {

  # Get the current local time
  my @localtime = localtime();

  # Get the current GMT time
  my @gmtime = gmtime();

  # Calculate the time difference in hours
  my $timezone = ($localtime[2] - $gmtime[2]);

  # If the day is different, adjust the timezone
  if ($localtime[3] != $gmtime[3]) {
    if ($localtime[3] < $gmtime[3]) {
        $timezone += 24;
    } else {
        $timezone -= 24;
    }
  }

  return $timezone; # e.g. -3

} # /get_timezone

print "Timezone: GMT " . &get_timezone() . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -le 'tzset; print for tzname'
CST
CDT
```

`tzset()` and `tzname()` functions from POSIX module can be a easily remembered answer.